# Context routing for two different apps

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I deploy **two different apps** to CF and I want to be able to use the context path routing for those two apps
e.g.

lets say I've two apps that deployed and I was able to consume it with the following URL.

```
1. app1.domain.com
2. app2.domain.com
```

Now I want somehow to use the context path routing of CF 
to be able to use this apps like following

```
1. something.domain.com/app1

2. something.domain.com/app2
```

My question are:

> 1. I missing the "something", what should I put in the apps manifest to be able to use it like above ?
> 2. How should I define the routes in the mainfest.yml file?
> 3. what should I put in the path?

Example will be very helpful

https://www.cloudfoundry.org/context-path-routing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucky that I recently prepared a [blog post](http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/01/context-path-routing-of-apps-and.html) and a [tutorial on context path routing](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting). Here is a sample `manifest.yml` taken from the tutorial that shows two apps with different routes on the same domain:

```
# This manifest deploys two applications.
#
# Both use the same host and domain name as defined
# by their respective route(s) property. The first app
# uses the root path, the second the "sub" and
# "lower" paths.

applications:
# The Python app starts here
- name: yourname-myapp
  memory: 256M
  command: python myapp.py
  routes:
  - route: yourname-myapp.mybluemix.net
  path: ./top/
# The Node.js app starts here  
- name: yourname-myapp-node
  routes:
  - route: yourname-myapp.mybluemix.net/lower
  - route: yourname-myapp.mybluemix.net/sub
  path: ./lower/
```

You can even define multiple routes for a single app, all in a single manifest file. The `routes` property is the place for the routing information. Note that the `path` points to the source code for the app (if done this way) and that you need a recent version of `cf` CLI to deploy it. See the [tutorial](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting) for more information and additional links.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , I try something like this and its not working , please see my update ...any idea what am I missing here ?

Comment: Could you remove the update and ask separately? Likely this requires some code. Is your app waiting for that path? My tutorial has code that prints out the path passed to the app

Comment: Done , please have a look at the following and see if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647896/cf-context-path-routing-is-not-working , Thanks!

Comment: Now remove the update here and mark it complete... :)

Comment: Done, I've removed it from the question :)

Comment: A common misconception I hear with path based routing is that users think the platform will rewrite the URL.  Ex: if you an app mapped to the path `/top` and have a request `/top/a`, users expect that the app to which the route has been mapped will get a request for `/a`.  That's false.  No rewriting occurs and a request to `/top/a` will be passed to the app as `/top/a`.  Make sure your app is designed to handle that.

Comment: Yup, see the newer question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find a good example in the map route documentation per below

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#map-route